# How do I get the value in TextInput when onBlur is called?

Tags: react-native

In React Native, I want to pass the value of the `TextInput` in the `onBlur` event handler.

```
onBlur={(e) => this.validateText(e.target.value)}
```

`e.target.value` works for plain React. But, in react-native, `e.target.value` is undefined. What is the structure of event args available in React Native?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In React Native, you can get the value of the TextInput from `e.nativeEvent.text`.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `multiline={true}`.  One hack around this is to maintain a ref to your `TextInput` and access the text value through the `_lastNativeText` property of the component.  For example (assuming you've assigned your `TextInput` component a ref of "textInput"):

`onBlur={() => console.log(this.refs.textInput._lastNativeText)}`

Comment: Nice catch.  After some more testing, I just updated the answer with a potential work around.

Comment: I filed an issue in react-native repo: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9548

Comment: The work around that I used is to use onEndEditing instead of onBlur.

Comment: Does this work with multiple textInputs present on a given component? (with a single ref?)

Answer (score 49):

You should use the 'onEndEditing' method instead of the 'onBlur'

> onEndEditing?: function Callback that is called when text input ends.

onBlur is a component function where onEndEditing is specific for TextInput

[onEndEditing](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onendediting)

This approach works for both multiline and single line.

```
<TextInput 
    onEndEditing={(e: any) => 
    {
        this.setState({textValue: e.nativeEvent.text})
    }
}/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Simple solution:
This way onBlur your state's email will always have the last value changed by the user.

```
           validate = () => {
            const { email } = this.state
            console.log('Validating Email Here!', email)
           }

          <TextInput
           style={styles.input}
           placeholder='E-mail'
           onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
           onBlur={e => this.validate()}
         />
```