# how get values of components react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, components

I want to get the value of the email and passowrd in my Form.js, so that click click button can pass them a client api
1. this is my class  src/components/login/Form.js

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';  
        import {
            KeyboardAvoidingView,
            StyleSheet,
            TouchableHighlight,
            Image,        
        } from 'react-native';
        import UserInput from "./UserInput";       
        import usernameImg from '../../images/Iconperson.png';
        import passwordImg from '../../images/Iconlock.png';
        import eyeImg  from '../../images/eye.png';       
            export default class Form extends Component {    
              constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                    email: "",
                    password: "",
                };
        }  
        _onPress() {
           console.warn("email", this.state.email)
           console.warn("password", this.state.password)
      }  
          render() {
              return (
                  <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding'
                    style={styles.container}>
                    <UserInput source={usernameImg}
                   onChangeText = {(email) => this.setState({email})}
                        keyboardType = 'email-address'
                        placeholder='Username'
                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                        returnKeyType={'done'}
                        autoCorrect={false} />
                    <UserInput source={passwordImg}
                 onChangeText = {(password) => this.setState({password})}
                        placeholder='Password'
                        returnKeyType={'done'}
                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                        autoCorrect={false} />
                    <TouchableHighlight
                        onPress={this._onPress}
                        activeOpacity={1} >
                        <Text>LOGIN</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>

              );
          }
      }   
      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
        }
    });
```

2. this is my class   src/components/login/UserInput.js

```
    import React, { Component , PropTypes} from 'react';
    import Dimensions from 'Dimensions';
    import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    TextInput,
    Image,
    } from 'react-native';  
    const DEVICE_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const DEVICE_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

    export default class UserInput extends Component {
      render() {
          return (
              <View style={styles.inputWrapper}>
                <Image source={this.props.source}
                    style={styles.inlineImg} />
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText = {(this.props.ChangeText) => 
                    this.setState({field})}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
                    autoCorrect={this.props.autoCorrect}
                    autoCapitalize={this.props.autoCapitalize}
                    returnKeyType={this.props.returnKeyType}
                    placeholderTextColor='white'
                    keyboardType ={this.props.keyboardType}
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent' />
            </View>

          );
      }
    }

    UserInput.propTypes = {
    ChangeText : PropTypes.string,
    source: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    keyboardType : PropTypes.string,
    secureTextEntry: PropTypes.bool,
    autoCorrect: PropTypes.bool,
    autoCapitalize: PropTypes.string,
    returnKeyType: PropTypes.string,
    };
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    input: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)',
        width: DEVICE_WIDTH - 40,
        height: 40,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        paddingLeft: 45,
        borderRadius: 20,
        color: '#ffffff',
    },
    inputWrapper: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    inlineImg: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 99,
        width: 22,
        height: 22,
        left: 35,
        top: 9,
    },
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are typing into the TextInput I see you are trying to change the state in the Form component. For this to happen correctly, setState needs to be called from the Form component. There are a couple functions currently being passed down through props:

```
(email) => this.setState({email})
// and
(password) => this.setState({password})
```

Looking at how those are being used in your **UserInput** component, whenever a new character is added to that text box, invoke the function above. so when `this.setState()` is called, it is saying `UserInput.setState()`. Since we want to change the state in **Form** we have to bind those functions to the parent component.

Instead of passing the functions directly to props, let's add some user methods:

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {}

  _onChangeEmail(email) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, state, { email })); // good practice for immutability
  }

  _onChangePassword(password) {
    this.setState(Object.assign({}, state, { password })); // good practice for immutability
  }

  render() {}
}
```

Next, we need to **bind these class methods to itself.** That way no matter where these are called, this will always point to the Form component. This is most commonly done in the constructor:

```
export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}

    // this is where we do the binding
    this._onChangeEmail = this._onChangeEmail.bind(this)
    this._onChangePassword = this._onChangePassword.bind(this)
  }

  _onChangeEmail(email) { /* code */}

  _onChangePassword(password) { /* code */}

  render() {}
}
```

Now pass these down to the UserInput component through props:

```
// Form.js
render() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <UserInput onChangeText={this._onChangeEmail} />
      <UserInput onChangeText={this._onChangePassword} />
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}
```

These methods should now be used when the user inputs text:

```
export default class UserInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image  />
          <TextInput onChangeText = {this.props.onChangeText} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Bonus: You also should add a property 'value' to the text input:

```
export default class UserInput extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image  />
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText} />
            value={this.props.textValue} 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And make sure it is passed down from the parent component:

```
// Form.js
render() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <UserInput
        onChangeText={this._onChangeEmail}
        textValue={this.state.email}/>
      <UserInput
        onChangeText={this._onChangePassword}
        textValue={this.state.password}/>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you could tell me how to do this, given that already searched and I can not find anything like it, thank you very much

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I answered from my phone earlier so I couldn't do it.  Give me a sec to put it together.

Comment: There it is! That should do it! :D

Answer (score 0):

The value of TextInput may be retrieved through its `_lastNativeTextproperty`.

```
this.refs.myTextInput._lastNativeText
```

See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106633/how-do-i-get-the-value-in-textinput-when-onblur-is-called)