# Alternative to Textfield onChange that behaves like HTML onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Textfield component nested within other components and pass a function pointer down to it as a prop. Currently I have a function that passes the contents of the Textfield back up to the root component that is called with onChange. Looking at the API for Textfield, this function is called whenever a change is made, unlike the onChange method for  in HTML which is called only when the form element loses focus.

The rest of the framework is written with React and this component is nested within another component within a Grid.

```
function Description(props) {

  const {updateDescription} = props;

  function changeDescription(event) {
    updateDescription(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <br></br>
      <TextField 
          margin="dense" 
          id="desc-input"
          type="text"
          onChange={changeDescription}
          multiline
          fullWidth
      />
    </>
  );  
}
```

Is there an alternative to this that does not call the function after every change, but rather when Textfield loses focus?

Comment: Try onBlur if TextField supports

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value in TextInput when onBlur is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106633/how-do-i-get-the-value-in-textinput-when-onblur-is-called)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `onBlur` event which is called when field loses focus

```
<TextField 
          margin="dense" 
          id="desc-input"
          type="text"
          onBlur={changeDescription}
          multiline
          fullWidth
      />
```